# Taking characters to the left of a character

Tags: r

Given some data

```
hello <- c('13.txt','12.txt','14.txt')
```

I want to just take the numbers and convert to numeric, i.e. remove the .txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions using the function gsub on the "hello" object in your original post.

```
hello <- c('13.txt','12.txt','14.txt')
as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*","\\1",hello))
#[1] 13 12 14
```

Answer (score 7):

You want `file_path_sans_ext` from the `tools` package

```
library(tools)
hello <- c('13.txt','12.txt','14.txt')
file_path_sans_ext(hello)
## [1] "13" "12" "14"
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't install that package on my current setup for some reason, is there another way using basic R syntax?

Comment: @luke123 -- `tools` is part of the standard R distribution. You shouldn't have to install it, just call library

Comment: @mnel recently discovered this one myself and have loved it just for these situations. +1

Comment: reputation aside, I'm totally saddened that a solution that requires loading a special package (a dependency) gets more upvotes than the pure base-R solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Another regex solution

```
hello <- c("13.txt", "12.txt", "14.txt")
as.numeric(regmatches(hello, gregexpr("[0-9]+", hello)))
## [1] 13 12 14
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know your extensions are all `.txt` then you can use `substr()`

```
> hello <- c('13.txt','12.txt','14.txt')
> as.numeric(substr(hello, 1, nchar(hello) - 3))
#[1] 13 12 14
```